# Icons do not show when I navigate to a new component

Tags: blazor

I have a Blazor WASM app and I use a template which comes with a lot of icons. The feather icons load properly on startup or if I reload any page/component, but if I try to navigate to another component without actually reloading the whole page, the icons do not load. This is how call the icons in `index.html`.

```
<body class="app">
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script>
        setTimeout(function () {
            feather.replace();
        }, 3000)
    </script>
</body>
```

Since it is a single-paged application, it seems the icons do not persist or not passed along when a new child component replaces the old one.
This is the main layout.

```
<div class="flex">
    <SideBar />
    <div class="content">
        @Body
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That would be the expected behaviour for a SPA. When this is some fade-in/out effect you might be able to trigger it form OnAfterRenderAsync(true).

Comment: @HenkHolterman Do you mean I should trigger the feather icons from OnAfterRender()? I now trigger it from oninitialized for every component, it works but, still lagging in a component with a lot icons.

Comment: well, I don't know what you want to see when. It depends, you have multiple points in the 'life cycle'. Experiment with the *Async versions.

Comment: @HenkHolterman Thanks. It worked with OnAfterRenderAsync