# Feather Icons do not appear in Blazor Shared Component

Tags: css, blazor, blazor-webassembly, feathericons

The HTML design that I'm using in my WASM application uses [feathericons](https://feathericons.com/), I linked the `css` and the `js` files in `wwwroot/index.html`. When I want to use the icons, for example:

```
<i data-feather="grid"></i>
```

if I use it inside `wwwroot/index.html` the icon appears, but if I use it in shared component `MainLayout.razor` the icon doesn't appear.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Could you put the `index.html` and `ManiLoyout.razor` into your question please?

Answer (score 1):

I have been battling with this myself in my own Blazor app. I suspect that it may be attempting to run the `feather.replace()` before the page is loaded.

My solution for now has been to add in a timeout as I saw used in [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67048970/icons-do-not-show-when-i-navigate-to-a-new-component).

**At the end of your body in index.html add:**

```
<script>
    setTimeout(function () {
        feather.replace();
    }, 3000)
</script>
```

If I have issues with this or something changes as I'm developing my site then I'll update this post with details.